# Magento 2: Unable to change category sort direction to descending

Tags: magento2.4, product-sorting, custom-layout-update

I've been unable to change the default sort direction for a category to descending. I've tried putting the XML in different files but none have had any effect.

The first thing I tried was using "Custom Layout Update", with an XML in `app/design/frontend/MYVENDOR/MYTHEME/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view_selectable_MYID_name.xml`

With the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
                <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                    <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

The custom layout update field appears in the admin panel, but the dropdown is empty.

I also tried putting it in `app/code/design/frontend/MYVENDOR/MYTHEME/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` as well as  `app/code/design/frontend/MYVENDOR/MYTHEME/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view_id_MYID.xml`

I've also tried multiple different names for the reference block such as product_list and product_list_toolbar.

I've cleaned the cache multiple time and re-deployed static content to no effect.

This is on a site running Magento 2.4.3.

Any ideas of what I can try next?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, changing the sorting of a collection need to be done where the collection is get; it has nothing to do with an xml file file.

So I would rather add something like that

```
$collection->setOrder('FIELD_YOU_WANT_TO_ORDER', 'DESC');
```

You should be able to retrieve it and customize it as much as you want from your block class.